# How can I fix this button layout after upgrading from bootstrap 4.1.3 to 4.5.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I found [this codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/KOhBlvCrMP/bootstrap-4-numeric-keypad-_-calculator) for a simple Code Pad button layout, which aliged perfectly in `bootstrap 4.1.3`:

[image: Nicely aligned layout]

After upgrading to `bootstrap 4.5.0`, the last row is unfortunately misaligned:

[image]

Can I fix this in `bootstrap 4.5.0` or do I need to have a different approach like putting the buttons into a table or something?

Here's the raw HTML in case the link goes dead:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical ml-4 mt-4" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input class="text-center form-control-lg mb-2" id="code">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '1';">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '2';">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '3';">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '4';">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '5';">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '6';">6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '7';">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '8';">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '9';">9</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value.slice(0, -1);">&lt;</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '0';">0</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary py-3" onclick="">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widths were adjusted by the contents. You can simply use the grid system by adding class `col` to each cell:

```html
<div class="btn-group-vertical ml-4 mt-4" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input class="text-center form-control-lg mb-2" id="code">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '1';">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '2';">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '3';">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '4';">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '5';">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '6';">6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '7';">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '8';">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '9';">9</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value.slice(0, -1);">&lt;</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 col" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '0';">0</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary py-3 col" onclick="">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

See this codeply: https://www.codeply.com/p/S3Y4S3KwW3

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the same width for each box (button). And since `btn-group > .btn` has `flex: 1 1 auto;`, which means they will shrink if necessary, you're safe to set each button 50% width, or 100% width:

```html
<div class="btn-group-vertical ml-4 mt-4">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input class="text-center form-control-lg mb-2" id="code">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">9</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">&lt;</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 w-100">0</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary py-3 w-100" onclick="">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/dmch1590/16/

If you look at Bootstrap 4.1.3, what differs it from 4.5.0 is that it has:

```css
.btn-group-vertical .btn {
    width: 100%;
}
```